# How to access local json file via svelte?

Tags: javascript, async-await, svelte

For now I use onMount async function to access

```
const dataAPI = './jsfwperf.json';
let data = [];

onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(dataAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

But in terminal it shows that file is missing

```
bundles src/main.js → public\build\bundle.js...
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
```

File location is the same as app.svelte that I used.
How can I proper access local json file via svelte?

Comment: Does the error not make it clear? "you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files"

Comment: Yes. I installed and imported it already. But still occurs

Comment: And you included the plugin in your rollup config like the [docs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/json#readme) say?

Answer (score 20):

In command line :

```sh
cd yourproject
npm install @rollup/plugin-json --save-dev
```

Edit the `rollup.config.js` file:

```js
// add at the beginning of the file :
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'

//...

// under the plugin line :
plugins: [
  json({
    compact: true
  }),

//...
```

In your svelte component :

```html
<script>
import * as myjson from './test.json'
</script>

<p>{myjson.mykey}</p>
```

Comment: It throws the error: "[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "movies.json" from "src\lib\svelte-component.svelte". Does the file exist?"

Comment: Excuse me, I actually used a blank project made with vite (npm create vite@latest myapp -- --template svelte) and it doesn't create rollup.config.js file. However, it works if I use 'npx degit' for creating an app. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the answer is about Rollup bundler. Using Vite, you should refer to its documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It works well. Could I please ask you how to do the same with writing to a local json file? I googled, but couldn't find it. Sorry for 'off topic'. Any clues and tips would be appreciated.

Comment: From the browser you can't write a file to the filesystem. You can generate a file to download it.

Answer (score 7):

```
<script>
    import item from 'path/to/data.json';
</script>
```