# svelte - reading json file from local folder

Tags: json, svelte, rollup

My `svelte` app is required to read `json` file from the public folder.
I followed exactly the `rollup` setup from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779816/how-to-access-local-json-file-via-svelte), then add `json` to my `app.svelte`:

```
import * as port from '/port.json';
```

`port.json` is located at the public folder together with `index.html`.
But I keep getting this error:

> main.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: port is not defined at main.js:11

and I am getting this message from `Terminal` which I am not sure what it means:

> (!) Missing global variable name Use output.globals to specify browser
> global variable names corresponding to external modules /port.json
> (guessing 'port')

How can I resolve this?

Comment: if the file is located in public, why not use fetch() with the relative path to the json file to read it then parse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Move the file to your `src/` folder and bundle it with the rest of your application code using Rollup. This is where you need `@rollup/plugin-json` to bundle json files. You can then import it like so:

```
<script>
    import json from './port.json';
</script>

<p>{JSON.stringify(json)}</p>
```

2. Keep the file in your `public/` folder and retrieve it at runtime using fetch.

```
<script>
    let fetchJson = fetch('port.json').then(res => res.json());
</script>

{#await fetchJson}
    <p>Loading JSON</p>
{:then result}
    <p>{JSON.stringify(result)}</p>
{/await}
```

Answer (score 0):

Export the object and rename the file from `.json` to `.json.js`.

port.json.js

```
export let myJson = {
    name: "hello world"
}
```

Component:

```
<script>
   import json from './port.json';
</script>

    
    <p>{JSON.stringify(json)}</p>
```